# How can I check a variable exist in returned collection relationship or not

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.8, laravel-relations

I have this relationship in `User.php` Class:

```
public function favourites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'favourite_products', 'usr_id', 'prd_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

And I have added `$user_favourites = \App\User::find(auth()->user()->usr_id);` to return info of a user.

Then, if I `@dd($user_favourites->favourites)`, I get this as result:

[image]

Now I wanted to check if the current product id is equals to the `prd_id` of returned collection (which is shown as **14** in the image).

So how can I do that?

I tried adding this to the Model, but returned an error:

```
public function available_favourite($id) {
        return $this->favourites()->where('prd_id','=', $id);
    }
```

And call it like this:

`@dd($user_favourites->available_favourite($product->prd_id)->get())`

And here is the error:

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'prd_id' in where clause is ambiguous**

So how can I check that current product id exist in `$user_favourites->favourites` ?

Comment: Can you share the table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the collection's `contains` method to check if such `prd_id` exists.

```
public function available_favourite($id) : bool 
{
   return $this->favourites->contains('prd_id', $id);
}

//then check
dd($user_favourites->available_favourite($product->prd_id))
```

exclude `()` in `$this->favourites()` just to reference the relationship.

[More info.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains)

Comment: Would u check this plz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997829/how-can-i-do-this-with-eloquent-relationship